# Upgraded R but RTVS points to old version

Tags: r, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, rtvs

I'm using R Tools for Visual Studio (RTVS version 1.0.30321.1407) in Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015 (version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3).  I've been using R version 3.3.1, but today I installed R version 3.4.0.

My RStudio was smart enough to now point to the new version of R, but my RTVS is still pointing to the old one.

**How do I get RTVS to point to the latest version of R?**

*Addendum:*  The solution is *not* to simply uninstall the old R from my machine.  That just makes Visual Studio hang for what seems like forever upon startup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, it turns out, is to get the latest version (1.1) of RTVS because this is a known bug as discussed [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/RTVS/issues/3494).

It's not obvious where to download it from, but I found it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/rtvs/installation#installing-rtvs-in-visual-studio-2015).